# Behaviour of single quotes with `luaquotes` packages is not consistent

Tags: quotation

Here is my MWE with the `luaquotes`package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luaquotes}
% \smartquotes
\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes}
\begin{document}

\section{Test of \texttt{luaquotes} package}

\noindent 'Single' 'Single' 'Single'\\

\noindent "Double" "Double" "Double".
  
\end{document}
```

Why is the first single quote reversed? I find the single quote behaviour inconsistent. How may I get consistent behaviour?

Uncommenting the line `\smartquotes` does not affect the result.

Comment: This is something that should be reported to the developer so that they can fix this counter-intuitive behaviour or at least mention it in the docs. (Ideally, you'd make a fully minimal example that does not involve `csquotes` at all for the report.)

Comment: Curiously, the presence/absence of `\noindent` changes where the undesirable behaviour happens. With `\noindent` it's the first pair of quotes, without it's the second.

Comment: I see this was already mentioned on the `luaquotes` bug tracker: https://github.com/ezgranet/luaquotes/issues/3

Comment: @moewe: Ditto to all your comments. Commenting out the `csquotes` content does not alter results; but leaving out `\noindent` does swap the error position. I will await resolution from the developer.

Comment: Since `csquotes` has nothing to do with the issue, I suggest you minimise your example document to exclude `csquotes` and also remove the `csquotes` tag.

Comment: Dev here—I'm taking a look now. Will answer soon. Thanks for finding this and apologies this apparent bug slipped in!
Edit: quick check shows this is an issue with the feature designed to allow smart elision (like ’ello for hello).  I will fix this and push an update to CTAN and make a full answer once I repair the code

Comment: @moewe: Both your suggestions have been implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for this bug! It's been fixed and will be on CTAN soon with version 1.2.1.  In the meantime, you can download the updated version of the package on the GitHub which produces the correct results. https://github.com/ezgranet/luaquotes

Update:thanks to CTAN maintainers for their customary speed and efficiency. The updated package is now available  on CTAN and pushed via the usual channels for updates.

Comment: The change has been propagated through the latest TeXLive update and the behaviour of single quotes is as expected. Thank you.